# Cannot get the addition to output

Tags: java

Everything is good, but i just cant get the addition to show up? When I run the program it is blank when it comes to the addition of the matrixes part. Thanks in advance. BtW does anyone know how I would make this display right column justified?

```
public static void displayMatrixes(int[][] matrix1, int[][] matrix2, int[][] resultsMatrix) {
     System.out.println("This is how i want it to output");
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                 System.out.print(matrix1[i][j] + " ");
             }
                  System.out.print("+ ");
                  for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                    System.out.print(matrix2[i][j]+ " ");
            }
            System.out.print("= ");
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                System.out.print(resultsMatrix[i][j]+ " ");
            }
                 System.out.println();
        }

        )
```

This is my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MatrixAdd
{

   public static void main(String arg[])
  {
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       int a[][]= new int[3][3];
       int b[][] = new int[3][3];

       int row, column;

    System.out.println("\nEnter Matrix A:  \n");
     for (int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j<3 ; j++){
                a[i][j] = input.nextInt();
            }

      }
          System.out.println("\nEnter Matrix B: \n");
         for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
                    b[i][j] = input.nextInt();
                }

      }
        System.out.println("\nMatrix A + Matrix B = Matrix C: \n");

        int[][] resultingMatrix = addMatrix(a, b);

    }



    public static int[][] addMatrix(int[][] a, int[][] b){

        int[][] result = new int[a.length][a[0].length];

        for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < result[0].length; j++){
            result[i][j]=a[i][j] + b[i][j];
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            char plus = '+';
            for (int j = 0; j < a[0].length; j++) {
                System.out.print("  " + a[i][j]);
            }

            if (i == a.length / 2)
                System.out.print("  " + plus + "  ");
            else {
                System.out.print("  ");
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < b[0].length; j++) {
                System.out.print("  " + b[i][j]);
            }

            if (i == a.length / 2)
                System.out.print("  =  ");
            else {
                System.out.print("  ");
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < result[0].length; j++) {
                System.out.print("  " + "  " + result[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    return result;
    }//end of add matrices

}//end of class
```

Comment: Certainly doesn't seem like "everything is good" if you're having trouble...

Comment: The `displayMatrixes` function receives **3** arguments, while you are only passing **2**.

Comment: Where is the addition happening?

Comment: @JunedAhsan  There mistake on my part

Answer (score 2):

I doubt that the given program compiles. In this line: `int[][] resultsMatrix = displayMatrixes(a, b);` you are expecting an `int[][]`, but in your method `displayMatrixes` you are not returning anything. You are also expecting a 3rd parameter which you are not passing.

Also, the `displayMatrixes` method has no return value, which since you are returning something at the end, you must have. Try it again like so:

```
    public static void main(String arg[]) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a[][] = new int[3][3];
    int b[][] = new int[3][3];

    int row, column;

    System.out.println("\nEnter Matrix A:  \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            a[i][j] = input.nextInt();
        }

    }
    System.out.println("\nEnter Matrix B: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            b[i][j] = input.nextInt();
        }

    }
    System.out.println("\nMatrix A + Matrix B = Matrix C: \n");

    displayMatrixes(a, b);        

}

public static void displayMatrixes(int[][] a, int[][] b) {

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            System.out.print(a[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.print("+ ");
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            System.out.print(b[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.print("= ");
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            System.out.print((a[i][j] + b[i][j]) + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }        
}
```

}

Comment: i do not get why people down vote without mentioning their reasons? so odd

Comment: @KickButtowski: I know... There should be a rule that downvoting either requires you to comment or else sort of endorse someone else's comments... how can one possibly improve upon an answer when he/she does not know what was done wrong?

Comment: @KickButtowski (and npinti) I wasn't a downvoter, but this has been discussed to death on Meta, and the explanation apparently is that anonymous voting > explanations for downvotes.

Comment: @KickButtowski See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63439/begging-for-votes). Don't ask for votes.

Comment: @user3580294 Did I beg for vote? lol

Comment: @KickButtowski You did. Don't edit and pretend nothing happened.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56081/discussion-between-kick-buttowski-and-user3580294).

Answer (score -2):

printf with The "%3d" specifier means a minimum width of three spaces, which, by default, will be right-justified.

for your right alignment question you can at http://alvinalexander.com/programming/printf-format-cheat-sheet

Comment: Please don't simply link off site - what happens if the link breaks? Instead, write an answer, address the whole question and explain.